# Validation error in Marketing cloud while saving Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a Journey builder where I am using standard data extension for Lead and I have three Lead email in this Journey builder so I am getting validation error in Journey builder.

[image]
Email content something like this:-

[image]

And the data extension is :

[image]

And Lead email is something like this:-

[image]

Comment: When it is a dataextension and not the global subscriber attribute i believe you have to grab those values via `%%[ set @columnname = [columnname] ]%%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the column names from your Data Extension, and not arbitrary global subscriber attributes. How I usually do this, is by using [AttributeValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) function. In your case, you can personalise your email in following way:

```
Hello %%=AttributeValue('Lead:FirstName')=%%,
```

Comment: Can you please let me know why I can't use arbitrary global subscriber attributes here?

Comment: Because your columns are not in the subscriber-modell of salesforce when you use them inside a dataextension. They would have to be in the global subscriber attributes list. There is even a dataview for that.